# Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.0' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I am following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>plats-bruts</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

but I have this problem on the pom:

```
Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.0' not found
```

but Its here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.0

Comment: First mvnrepository is not central. Apart from that you should show the error output ... which is not part of the post ... furthermore please try on plain command and check if something fails .... usually this is indicator for network error/proxy/firewall issue ... etc..

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I just ran into a similar problem. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.2. The version number 2.4.0 was red and the message was the same as yours.

Selecting File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... and choosing the Invalidate and Restart option fixed the issue. I guess it was just a stale cache.

Comment: Hmmm... that did not help to me :( IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Community Edition)

Comment: I got a similar issue when upgrade `spring-boot-starter-parent` to 2.7.7 from 2.7.5, and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Spring Boot's starter parent pom certainly [does exist in Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/classic/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.boot%7Cspring-boot-starter-parent%7C2.4.0%7Cpom).

I copied your `pom.xml` and ran `mvn test` using Maven 3.6.3.  All required libraries, including the parent pom were downloaded just fine.  You will probably want to look at your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file to see if any proxies are active that are preventing you from connecting to Maven Central.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was re-building and remote caches and then local caches. Here're the steps I followed (on Mac, please translate to your target environment):

1. Goto Preferences Menu: ie: IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences
2. Under Build Tools: ie: "Build, Execution, Deployment" > Build Tools
3. Select Repositories: ie: Maven > Repositories
4. Notice the Remote and Local repositories, and the Update button
5. Select Each repository and click Update. This will take a while depending on your internet speed, but it will do a complete check of the broken downloads and stale Maven caches

Answer (score 4):

In my case `mvn clean` and than `mvn package` helped me with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just reload your Maven project in the IDE. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to run `mvn spring-boot:run` directly.

You can use the wrapper instead cf. `./mvnw spring-boot:run` This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2021.1.1. The version number 2.5.4 Spring Boot.
[I just restarted Intellij and the error was fixed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WBNd.png)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Double check if your internet provider is blocked [maven repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ site mistakenly.

I also encounter with this problem. For my case, I tried everything, like invalidate cache and restart Intellij, re-import the maven dependencies. But those are not working for me.

When I try to re-import the maven dependencies with my mobile data, then everything is okay. So, there was a problem with my internet provider.

After I inform them, then I was fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was face same issue due to version incompatibility

when  change the version  spring-boot-starter-parent 3.1.5 to 3.1.1 the issue resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with spring boot project and restarting IntelliJ IDE worked for me